# Python 3 with WPF

Tags: wpf, python-3.x

I would like to develop a WPF project using Python. Sadly, the IronPython website (http://ironpython.net/) says it is only compatible with Python 2. Is there a way to build a WPF project using Python 3?

Comment: Interesting idea but why you do not want to use C#?

Comment: Because I code faster in python :)

Comment: Only if it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

***IronPython is compatible with Python 3 - https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3.*** If you want to code on C# - use native .NET and C# WPF. If you wanna code on Python 2 - use .NET interface of [IronPython 2](http://ironpython.net). And if you wanna code on Python 3 - use .NET interface of [IronPython 3](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3).